# etymology of "Bnei Blial"

Tags: hebrew, translation, samuel-shmuel-book-of

The term "בְּנֵי בְלִיָּעַל" appears several times in Shmuel (e.g., [1Sam 2:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a02.htm#12)).  It is usually translated along the lines of "dishonorable people".  Where does בְלִיָּעַל come from?  Are there other books where it's used?

Comment: Are you asking where else in Tanach it is found?

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%9C

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks!  That's an answer if you want it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

בליעל appears [many times in Tanach](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=003922636974222575695%3Adxq675sw--g&ie=windows-1255&q=%E1%EC%E9%F2%EC&hq=inurl%3A%2Fi%2Ft%2F&sa=+%E7%F4%F9%21+#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%9C&gsc.page=1) and appears to be a compound word: בלי (=without) and יעל. Three possible meanings are given [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%3a%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%9C):

- בלי יעל where יעל derives from the root ע-ל-ה = to go up. The people are 'without going up' implying they will go down to Gehonim.
- בלי יעל where יעל derives from the root י-ע-ל  = purpose (like the words הועיל and תועלת).  The people in this case are 'without purpose' meaning they are a waste of space/time etc.
- בלי עֹל where עֹל means a yoke. The people then are 'without a yoke' meaning they have rejected the yoke of Torah. (This, from the Malbim and Metzudat David.)